# Facebook feed- picture is not coming

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

When I am posting a feed to my wall every thing is working properly,but the picture is not coming .

```
$ret_obj = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'access_token' => $access_token,
                                      'name' =>'Andameter',
                                      'caption' =>'Rating of Andameter',
                                      'source' => 'http://mydomainname/Andameter/uploads',
                                      'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/myappname',
                                      'message' => $pic_category.' : '.$user_name.' rated '.$pic_title.' with '.$indiv_likes_count.' &bs and '.$indiv_dislikes_count.' andas. What\'s about you ?', 
                                      'picture' => 'http://mydomainname/Andameter/uploads/tech1.jpg',
                                      'description' => $pic_description

                                 ));
            echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
```

can anybody help me where my mistake is?

Comment: How did you expect this to work?

Comment: Ok I am agree with you, but after uploading to web server nothing is getting on my wall.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your picture Url is containing Localhost which can not resolved by Facebook. You have to pass a valid domain so that your picture can come in facebook. Upload you code in the server if any and pass the complete Url your code, it will work.

Comment: When was running on localhost only picture not getting,but after upload to server it's totally not working.I am not getting any post on my wall.

Comment: Change your app settings. I think you have not updated your app settings

Comment: Yeah I have changed my canvas url.is there any more settings ??

Comment: for your information https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/